# Need the default SSL certificate validation in iOS app

Tags: ios, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

The iOS app needs the basic ssl validation to secure the client-server communication. I need a way to avoid SSL pinning which may have the client-server dependencies and need to update the app if the SSL cert changed.

Is there any way to allow all the valid SSL cert issued by any trusted CA's ?

Comment: Whoa. Before you go into pinning, have you checked https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/NetworkingOverview/SecureNetworking/SecureNetworking.html? "Connecting to a URL via TLS is trivial. When you create an `NSURLRequest` object to provide to the `initWithRequest:delegate:` method, specify `https` as the scheme of the URL instead of `http`. The connection uses TLS automatically with no additional configuration."

Comment: Tried the above and still I was able to interrupt the response using a proxy server.

Comment: Post your code that does the Https connection.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a way to bypass the transport security layer imposed by apple, you can do this.

Put the below code in your plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

*** This would disable the transport security layer and allow you to connect to insecure sources. Please beware that this is not recommended by apple and you should always use the TLS ***

Check out this link to understand apple's App Transport Security better. There might be some keys in this link that you can configure to achieve what you are looking for

http://www.neglectedpotential.com/2015/06/working-with-apples-application-transport-security/

Comment: The above will bypass all the certificates. Is there any we can allow only the SSL certificates issued by trusted CA's ?

Comment: l went thru the link you posted. Thing is how can we avoid man-in-the-middle-attack ? Currently the API response can be interrupted using a proxy server and able to manipulate the response.